# Callback with interface of generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic container interface that I use to abstract away Android `SparseArray` in Java code:

```
public interface MyContainer<T> {
    T get(int key);
    void forEach(Consumer<T> consumer);
}
```

And I have a class with a container of `Implementation`, but I only want to expose `Interface` externally:

```
MyContainer<Implementation> data;
Interface get(int key) {
    return data.get(key);
}
void method(Consumer<Interface> callback) {
   data.forEach(callback); //here
}
```

But I'm getting a compiler error:

```
error: incompatible types: Consumer<Interface> cannot be converted to Consumer<Implementation>
```

How can I alter `MyContainer` interface to allow `Consumer<Interface>` to be passed to my class?

Comment: How does Iterable<Implementation> allow passing a Consumer<Interface> in its forEach() method? Look at the javadoc, and do the same.

Comment: try changing MyContainer<T>#forEach to `void forEach(Consumer<? extends T> consumer);`

Comment: @f.khantsis: That's backwards: It would need to be `Consumer<T extends ?> consumer`, which isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 6):

In `MyContainer`, the `Consumer`'s type argument can have `T` as a lower bound.

```
void forEach(Consumer<? super T> consumer);
```

This way something that consumes a supertype of `T` can be passed in as an argument.

For the `Consumer` itself, if it can handle a supertype of `T`, then it can handle a `T` as well.  This is part of PECS - Producer Extends, Consumer Super.

Then, in `method`, you can pass a `Consumer<Interface>` to `forEach`.  Here, `T` is `Implementation`.  The type `Interface` is a supertype to `Implementation`, so this is allowed by the lower bound.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know I could use `super` there.